# Pip upgrade issue && Pytest Problems && MAC OS being uncooperative

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, pytest

## Issue

**1. Where my computer points to when trying to run things via python**

Whenever I attempt to run a python command in my terminal, the computer defaults to attempting to use Python 3.7, even though I have Python 3.8.1 installed on my laptop. This has caused issues when I try to install and use packages on my laptop for projects. The work around up till now has been to use a a virtual env, but this no longer seems to be working in my favor.

**2. The Current Issue: Attempting to use Pytest for some class work assignments, but getting**: `...venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 942, in <module> @attr.s(eq=False) TypeError: attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eq'`. After doing some looking around online to find a solution, it APPEARS to me that I simply needed to update a few out of date packages to get things running. Primarily  it seemed to be that I needed to update `attrs` and `py`.

This is where my second issue kicked off, as I tried to use the `pip3 install --upgrade attrs` command and `pip3 install --upgrade py` command and it would give:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pytest 6.2.2 requires py>=1.8.2, but you have py 1.8.0 which is incompatible.
```

or

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pytest 6.2.2 requires attrs>=19.2.0, but you have attrs 19.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

Finally Ending with a nice `Successfully installed attrs-20.3.0` or `Successfully installed py-1.10.0`

*Note: This was done in and out of virtual environment*

**3. Yet the packages didn't update**

Upon running the command `pip3 list --outdated` though - after running so many different commands for updating the packages - it would show that both `attrs` and `py` were still outdated (along with many others)

I have run up and down every site and thread that seemed related to the issue I have been facing, tried updating using every command I found, uninstalled and re-installed packages and pytest, and yet nothing seems to be working. Is there anyone out there who has faced a similar issue and can help point me in the right direction

### Simplification

I need to run pytest, my computer tries to use the wrong python version if I'm not in a virtual environment, I'm getting errors from packages supposed to help run pytest, and those packages won't get updated no matter what I do.

Comment: try `pip3 install --ignore-installed pytest` this will reinstall the library and its dependencies.

Comment: @virtualdvid This appears to run, the issue is that while something is being updated, its not looking at the updated packages when I try to run pytest. Not sure what it is, but my mac alwasy trys to default on using Python 3.7 and its packages and not the up to date version, ever since a OS update some time ago

Comment: Two possible cases. One is you are not activating the environment and it is running the default python version on your machine. Two if you don't have a virtual env. Check the environment variables and change its order so each time you run python the first option is the one you want.